# android - show spinner rather than keyboard on text field

Tags: android, input, keyboard, spinner

I'm in need of a method for changing the input of a text field from a keyboard to a spinner. Basically the text field is to enter your gender, and i only want the user to be able to select either male or female.

I've searched on Google however I have not been able to find what i need.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just use a spinner instead of a textfield? It will do the work. Just replace the textfield with a spinner in the layout and put something like this in your activity:

```
String[] spinnerGenderValue = {
            getString(R.string.male),
            getString(R.string.female),
            getString(R.string.gender)
    };
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(SignUpActivity.this, R.layout.spinner_item_dropdown, spinnerGenderValue){
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

            if (position == getCount()) {
                ((TextView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText("");
                ((TextView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setHint(getItem(getCount())); 
            }

            return v;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return super.getCount()-1; 
        }
    };

    gender_spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    gender_spinner.setSelection(adapter.getCount());
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to use a spinner and not a textView

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html

Answer (score 0):

I think it is best to use a Radio Group and Radio buttons for gender selection. It is also good for user experience. Selecting a gender using a spinner and selecting a gender using a text field that brings up a spinner takes two clicks. Using a radio group takes just one click.

But if however for some reason (insistent clients for example), you really need an edit text that brings up a spinner, you can set the onClickListener of the editText like so:

```
    editText.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //show a spinner dialog here
            showSpinnerDialog();
        }
    });
```

And then show the spinner as a pop up dialog.

```
public void showSpinnerDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Activity.this);
    String[] gender = {"Male", "Female"};

    builder.setTitle("Choose a gender:");
    builder.setItems(gender, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(Dialog dialog, int pos) {
            //save selected gender here
        }
    });

    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    Dialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
}
```

Please edit to suit your application. I would also recommend putting the dialog creation on the onCreateDialog() of your activity but I will leave that to you. :)